# printing double precision floating point numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, double, ieee-754

I'm trying to represent a double in a string, for this purpose i'm using grisu's algorithm, you can check it out here: https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf

i'm done with it, and apparently is working, my question comes when comparing with printf output with big precision, something like that:

```
double u = 1, t = 3;
double co = u/t;
printf("%.100f", co);
```

Outputs

```
0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

With grisu's algorithm i can obtain the following:

```
3333333333333333e-16
```

What is logic because the max precision you can get with double is 21 digits as you can read in the PDF at "5.3 C Implementation" (page 6). Then how can i obtain the rest if my max precision is this, or which algorithm is using printf to get this amount of precision?

Comment: Why would you believe 53 binary bits of precision to approach 21 decimal digits of precision?

Comment: Do you mean that with a 53 bits of mantissa i can't get this?

Comment: Round numbers, log-10 of 2^53 is ~15.9. So 15-16 digits of precision decimal. That seems to align with what you're observing.

Comment: `log10(pow(2, 53))` is not `21`.

Comment: then how can printf get those 54 digits from a double 64 bits?

Comment: From a 64 bits `double` only 15-16 digits are true. If you ask `prinff()` (or whatever algorithm) for more digits then you get undefined, garbage digits.

Comment: @latiagertrutis Becuase `10 == 5 * 2`, so base-10 only has a single factor of two.

Comment: @Ripi2 No, you do *not*  get garbage. You get the base-10 representation of the *exact* value as it was in base-2.

Comment: @EOF No, because the value in RAM comes from an also size-limited CPU register. OTH, it's true what you say if the value in RAM (base-2) is valid and exact.

Comment: @EOF: I'm not sure what the standard actually guarantees. Some implementation do so the exact decimal value (if you specify enough digits). Others might only show enough decimal digits to unambiguously represent the stored value.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Standard of what? C? IEEE 754?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: C (which defines the behavior of `printf`). The C standard says "The value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits.", which could be ambiguous.

Comment: *What is logic because the max precision you can get with double is 21*. You're misinterpreting the paper you cited. In section 5.3, the author is not referring to standard IEEE 754 floating point format when they mention 21 digits.

Comment: @KeithThompson: C 2011 [N1570] 5.2.4.2.2 6: “The accuracy of the floating-point operations (+, -, *, /) and of the library functions in <math.h> and <complex.h> that return floating-point results is implementation- defined, as is the accuracy of the conversion between floating-point internal representations and string representations performed by the library functions in <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h>, and <wchar.h>. The implementation may state that the accuracy is unknown.”

Comment: @lurker I was thinking on that, so the max precision i can get here is 16?

Comment: @lurker: The maximum number of decimal digits that can be converted, for any possible digits and exponent, from decimal floating-point to IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point and back without change is 15. The number of decimal digits required to convert any number from binary floating-point to decimal and back without change is 17.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks. I did hedge my bets with 15-16 initially (since the log-10 of 2^53 came in at 15.9...). So I thought perhaps there may be some cases where one could squeeze 16 digits out of it. So max 15 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fundamental principle of floating-point arithmetic, particularly as specified in the IEEE 754 standard, is that a floating-point datum represents **exactly** one specific number.

When performing an operation on floating-point numbers, the exact mathematical result might not be representable in the floating-point format. In this case, the operation returns the nearest representable number according to some rule (often round to nearest with ties to even digit, but sometimes round toward +infinity, round toward -infinity, round toward zero, or round to odd digit). Thus, **operations** in floating-point arithmetic may return approximate results, but **numbers** are exact.

In your example, dividing one by three results in a floating-point number that is exactly 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125. This is because the mathematical result is exactly ⅓, but that is not representable in binary floating-point, and the number shown above is the closest value that is representable, so that is the result.

The call to `printf` with the conversion specifier `%.100f` requests that this binary floating-point value be converted to decimal. That is a mathematical operation, and the mathematical result of converting the binary floating-point value to decimal would be “0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125”. Since you told `printf` to use 100 digits, it has enough digits to produce the exact result, so it does.

(This suggests that you are using a good-quality `printf` implementation. Some implementations do not perform this operation correctly.)

The paper by Florian Loitsch you cite provides algorithms for converting binary floating-point values to enough decimal digits that the value is distinguished from neighboring floating-point values. It does not usually generate enough decimal digits to show the exact value. For example, in base-3 floating-point with two digits, we could represent the numbers 0, 1/9, 2/9, 3/9, 4/9, and so on. In this case, if the value is 4/9 (.4444…), then printing “.4” would be enough to distinguish the value from .3333… and .5555…, but it would not exactly represent the value. Loitsch’s algorithms only produce enough digits to distinguish values, not usually enough to show the exact mathematical value.

(Loitsch’s paper also discusses how often the algorithms produce the shortest result that distinguishes the value—just enough digits to do the job and no more.)

The classic paper on converting between bases is *Correctly Rounded Binary-Decimal and Decimal-Binary Conversions* by David M. Gay.

Comment: @latiagertrutis: Why do you think `co` contains ⅓? It contains the result of dividing 1 by 3 **as a floating-point operation**. Since binary floating-point cannot represent ⅓, the result is not ⅓. Instead, it is the nearest representable value.

Comment: But my variable 'co' is a double number that contains the value 1/3 and his mantissa is: 10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101, so with this how printf does for obtain this aproximation?

Comment: To avoid miss understanding, i know that some numbers can't be represented with the finite size of a double, what i'm trying to find is witch method is printf using.

Comment: @latiagertrutis: The value printed by `printf` is not an approximation; it is **exactly** the value in `co`. I do not know which algorithm `printf` is using (I do not even know which `printf` you are using—Apple’s? One that came with GCC?). If you want an algorithm for doing this conversion, search for Gay’s paper. There appears to be a copy [here](https://ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf).

Comment: You should read Loitsch's article, and also Marc Andrysco, Ranjit Jhala, Sorin Lerner's “Printing Floating-Point Numbers: A Faster, Always Correct Method”. First, it would be better than guessing about them, and second, they provide exactly the sort of conversion, for better and for worse, at the core of some programming languages' conversion-to-decimal functions. https://ideone.com/Mw09aj

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Thanks, I’ve printed Loitsch’s paper and made a note of the other.

Answer (score -2):

The output from [that] printf is a false precision, in the sense that it is telling you the precise value of the binary number when rendered in decimal as if that binary number had an infinite number of 0 bits on the end, when we know the number probably started as decimal in the first place.

Comment: (a) The precision is not false; IEEE 754 is clear that a floating-point datum represents exactly one specific number (unless it is a NaN), and `printf` has correctly shown that number. (b) There is nothing about 1 or 3 or ⅓ that is particularly decimal; these would be the same in base 4, 7, 16, or 233. And ⅓ is not representable in decimal floating-point, so assuming values ought to be decimal in some regard is incorrect. The principles of IEEE 754 are good: Preserve values as much as possible. This means showing all digits when asked, not truncating arbitrarily for decimal.